# TypeScript - validate that value associated with a key is correct when using keyof

Tags: typescript

Assuming I have an interface like:

```
interface Foo {
  description: string;
  amount: number;
}
```

And a function to update Foo like:

```
public updateFoo(key: keyof Foo, val: string | number): void {
  this.foo = { ...foo, [key]: val }
}
```

When I call this function in TypeScript, this is obviously considered valid:

```
this.updateFoo('description', 10)
```

Is there a way for TypeScript to use the keys that it already knows belong to the target interface and validate the type of the second argument being passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you want to use a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints):

```
 public updateFoo<K extends keyof Foo>(key: K, val: Foo[K]): void {        
    this.foo = { ...this.foo, [key]: val };
    // or just this.foo[key] = val;
  }
```

The `key` parameter is a generic type `K` constrained to `keyof Foo`, and the `val` parameter is the [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) `Foo[K]`, meaning "the type of the property of `Foo` whose key is of type `K`".  This allows you to do the sort of type-safe property getting and setting that you're looking for.

Now if you try the offending code you get an error:

```
this.updateFoo('description', 10) // error, 10 not assignable to string
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: The reason I don't say `this.foo[key] = val` is to avoid mutations, I don't actually access the foo property directly it was just for the sake of brevity. I never knew `Foo[K]` was valid syntax, this is awesome.